# Disable SSL on a tomcat7 ubuntu server

Tags: tomcat, ssl, tomcat7

I am running a server which i need to disable SSL completely. Regardless of SSLv2 or SSLv3. I couldn't find the exact way of doing so. The server which i am hosting is having a valid ssl certificate too.

If i disable SSL in server.xml then i loose "https" and it is more troublesome.

This is what my server.xml connecter looks like:

```
 <Connector
        port="443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
        URIEncoding="UTF-8"
        scheme="https" secure="true" clientAuth="optional" 
        sslProtocols="TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2"
        sslEnabledProtocols="TLSv1,TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2"
        keystoreFile="${user.home}/Server.jks" keystorePass="secret"
        truststoreFile="${user.home}/Server.jks" truststorePass="secret"
        maxThreads="500" minSpareThreads="25"
        compression="on"
        compressionMinSize="2048"
        noCompressionUserAgents="gozilla, traviata"
        compressableMimeType="text/html,text/xml,text/plain,text/css,text/javascript,image/gif,image/png,image/jpeg,image/ico"
        ciphers="TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA"
    />
```

Moreover i am having openssl version `1.0.1-4ubuntu5.36` , what can i do to upgrade it ?

Comment: HTTPS needs SSL. How do you expect to server HTTPS if you disable SSL?

Comment: yep i know..,, only one thing is possible right,.. i am basically interested in disabling SSL as a whole,, even if i loose https

Comment: Just switch to a config which serves everything off of port 80 (plain HTTP). That can't be difficult to figure out.

Comment: @Rahul - I think OP wants to disable legacy SSL protocols but leave TLS protocols enabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SSLEnabled="true"
```

Change this to, err

```
SSLEnabled="false"
```

> If I disable SSL in server.xml then I lose "https"

Of course.

> and it is more troublesome.

More troublesome that what? Are you seriously asking for HTTPS support *without* SSL? Are you aware that's a contradiction in terms? Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: well i am still seeing `SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : SSLv3` when i do `openssl s_client -connect my_site:443 -ssl3`

Comment: @NishantSingh You need to use `-tls1` with `s_client` otherwise it will try to use an SSL handshake, not a TLS one.

Comment: @NishantSingh If you are seeing SSL at all you haven't executed this change. It remains unclear what you're really asking for.

Answer (score 0):

You want:

```
sslProtocol="TLS"
sslEnabledProtocols="TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2"
```

You also want a reasonably recent version of Tomcat and a reasonably recent version of Java.